# Bash Script continues after reboot?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I´ve written a simple bash Script to reboot and update my Ubuntu 12.04 server automatically via crontab.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo reboot

/usr/bin/apt-get -qy update > /dev/null
/usr/bin/apt-get -qy dist-upgrade > /dev/null

exit 0
```

The update section doesn´t work. The server only restarts.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Seriously?.....

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to reboot *before* a `dist-upgrade`.

Comment: As an aside, if this runs in root's crontab, then you don't need to use `sudo` before the `reboot` command. If it is running in another user's crontab, then you probably need to put a `sudo` before the `apt-get` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script calls reboot first which halts execution so the update, upgrade is never called. If you want to reboot put it at the end of the script.
Piping the outputs to /dev/null is also a bad idea in case something goes wrong.

Better use something like this:
[unattended-upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/automatic-updates.html)

It can notify you of the updates and problems and can also be configured to only perform security updates automatically

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cron`'s [special word `@reboot`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto#Advanced_Crontab) to run script after reboot. Edit your `crontab` with `crontab -e` to add:

```
@reboot apt-get --quiet --yes update > /dev/null && apt-get --quiet --yes  dist-upgrade > /dev/null
# or
@reboot update-after-reboot.bash
```

Comment: This will perform the same actions after every subsequent reboot, though.